# Exibir imagem salva no banco de dados e permitir que o usuário altere a imagem

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, front-end

Estou recuperando as informações do banco de dados e verificando se os campos de GIF e Imagem estão nulos ou não para exibir ao usuário a melhor opção na View Edit.

De qualquer forma, segue o código onde faço essa verificação:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <label class="control-label">Logo</label>
    @{
        if (Model.Logo == null)
        {
            <div class="input-group image-preview">
                <input class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled" type="text" />
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default image-preview-clear" style="display:none;">
                        <span class="icon-remove"></span> Limpar
                    </button>
                    <div class="btn btn-blue-grey image-preview-input">
                        <span class="icon-folder-open"></span>
                        <span class="image-preview-input-title">Selecionar</span>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" name="img" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            string imgbase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Logo);
            string imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imgbase64);

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="btn btn-blue-grey image-preview-input">
                    <span class="icon-folder-open"></span>
                    <span class="image-preview-input-title">Alterar</span>
                    <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" name="img" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-light-blue" id="view-img">
                    <span class="icon-eye2"></span> Visualizar
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <img src="@imgsrc" width="250" height="200" class="img-thumbnail" />
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

No caso de o campo estar nulo, consigo exibir ao usuário a opção de fazer o upload normalmente de um gif ou imagem, e ele consegue alterar normalmente antes de dar o post. Porém, a dificuldade vem quando já existe uma imagem salva no campo e eu preciso exibir.

Gostaria de exibir ao usuário uma forma dele visualizar a imagem que já está salva em um popup e caso ele queira alterar a imagem, mudar o campo para o mesmo que é exibido na situação onde o campo vem nulo.

Já faço alguma coisa com javascript quando o campo é nulo, mas não consigo visualizar uma solução quando a informação já existe no banco.

Comment: é realmente necessário vc persistir as imagens no banco de dados? Por que não salvar o arquivo fisicamente e guardar somente o caminho dele no banco de dados? ficaria muito mais simples e rápido e você não ia precisar converter nada, somente enviar o caminho da imagem.

Comment: Se possível também, poderia mostrar seu objeto? você tem uma array de bytes no atributo "Logo"?

Comment: Eu tenho um um byte array sim no atributo Logo. Quando capturo a imagem de um file com o HttpPostedFileBase tenho que converter pra byte array e salvar no banco. E sim, é necessário salvar a imagem.

Comment: A solução do Ayrton e a melhor alternativa, salvar o arquivo fisicamente e guardar somente o "nome da imagem" no banco de dados, o caminho você decide, pode até deixar uma opção externa para configurar o caminho, mais se for gravar no banco de dados, já fica sabendo que com pouco tempo seu banco vai ficar lento e para fazer um backup vai levar horas.

Answer (score 0):

Para exibir:

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RenderImage(int id)
    {
        Item item = await db.Items.FindAsync(id);

        byte[] photoBack = item.Image;

        return File(photoBack, "image/png");
    }
```

View:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", new { id = Model.Id})" />
```